Enumerate display output connectors on graphics adapter
I'm trying to enumerate and display information about the display output ports on a GPU.
E.g., on my GPU:
> Connector 0: HDMI
> Connector 1: DisplayPort
> Connector 2: DisplayPort
> Connector 3: DisplayPort

I need to get these even when there is nothing connected to them.
I tried with SetupApi, but did not find anything about connectors/outputs.
I tried EnumDisplayDevices() and EnumDisplayMonitors(), but this seems to return only connected monitors.
DXGI also only lists connected monitors at least in my attempts.
QueryDisplayConfig() with QDC.QDC_ALL_PATHS gives a lot of paths of which some seem nonsensical, as for example returning some with DVI, which my GPU doesn't have. Maybe there is a method to the madness here and I need to filter in some way?
Is this possible on Windows, without resorting to per-GPU vendor libraries?

Edit: I've found that the Windows Display Driver model in Dxgkddi has the methods to query adapter children (in this case, for GPU display outputs) in order to create the video present network topology. However, this doesn't help me since I need to develop an app, and not a driver, hence I need a higher level API.

Edit2: The following is the implementation with NVAPI. I need something similar in a vendor agnostic way, that works on W10+ for all gpus.
#include <Windows.h>
#include "NVGetOutputs.h"
#include <nvapi.h>
#include <iostream>

void NV_Outputs::getOutputs() {
    
    NvU32 displayIdCount = NVAPI_MAX_DISPLAYS;
    NV_GPU_DISPLAYIDS displayIds[NVAPI_MAX_DISPLAYS] = { 0 };
    displayIds->version = NV_GPU_DISPLAYIDS_VER;

    NvU32 gpuCount = 0;
    NvPhysicalGpuHandle gpuHandles[NVAPI_MAX_PHYSICAL_GPUS] = { 0 };
    
    NvAPI_Status status = NvAPI_Initialize();
    if (status != NVAPI_OK) {
        return;
    }

    status = NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs(gpuHandles, &gpuCount);
    if (status != NVAPI_OK || gpuCount < 1) {
        NvAPI_Unload();
        return;
    }

    NvPhysicalGpuHandle gpuHandle = gpuHandles[0];
    if (gpuHandle == 0) {
        NvAPI_Unload();
        return;
    }

    status = NvAPI_GPU_GetAllDisplayIds(gpuHandle, displayIds, &displayIdCount);
    if (status != NVAPI_OK) {
        NvAPI_Unload();
        return;
    }

    char* types[] = {
        "UNINITIALIZED",
        "VGA",
        "COMPONENT",
        "SVIDEO",
        "HDMI",
        "DVI",
        "LVDS",
        "DISPLAY PORT",
        "COMPOSITE",
        "UNKNOWN"
    };

    int connector = 0;
    for (NvU32 i = 0; i < displayIdCount; ++i) {
        if (displayIds[i].isOSVisible) {
            std::cout
                << "Output " << (i+1) << " on Port " << ++connector << ":" << std::endl
                << "  Type       : " << types[displayIds[i].connectorType] << std::endl
                << "  Connected  : " << displayIds[i].isConnected << std::endl
                << std::endl;
        }
    }

    NvAPI_Unload();
}


Interesting problem.  Many years ago, I've seen something similar by comparing the current card model number, with the current display configuration, with a database of cards and their available connectors, and how to identify them for when they are used in a current display configuration.  Maybe with todays APIs there's a more direct way to do that.

I guess this depends on the WDDM capabilities, but I'm not skilled enough to find the answer... But there is some pretty deep stuff that can be returned, like gpu fan rpm, and power, so it would make sense if there was.
